# Error Updating Child Entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Getting the following error when trying to update a model and its child collection:

An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ManufacturerViewModel form, string[] selectedCategories)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        UpdateCategories(selectedCategories, form.Manufacturer);
        //TODO: Handle links relationship
        db.Entry(form.Manufacturer).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(form);
}

private void UpdateCategories(string[] selectedCategories, Manufacturer mfr)
{
    var categoryIds = selectedCategories.Select(c => int.Parse(c)).ToList();
    foreach (var category in GetCategories())
    {
        if (categoryIds.Contains(category.ID))
        {
            if (!mfr.Categories.Contains(category))
                mfr.Categories.Add(category);
        }
        else
        {
            if (mfr.Categories.Contains(category))
                mfr.Categories.Remove(category);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue, I simply had to reverse the order of these lines:

```
UpdateCategories(selectedCategories, form.Manufacturer);
db.Entry(form.Manufacturer).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Is now:

```
   db.Entry(form.Manufacturer).State = EntityState.Modified;
   UpdateCategories(selectedCategories, form);
```